# How do I troubleshoot the EINVAL and EPERM errors I'm getting in this x86-64 assembly code using the mmap syscall on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, x86-64, system-calls

I'm having some trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong in this code, and I'd appreciate any help available:

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:
    # Grab our first argument from the stack
    popq %rdi # This will be argc, which we don't care about
    popq %rdi # Now the executable's path
    popq %rdi # And the first argument, at last

    # Open the file with open(argv[1], 0, O_RDONLY)
    movq $2, %rax # The syscall number for open
    xor %rsi, %rsi # There are no flags we need to specify
    xor %rdx, %rdx # O_RDONLY is 0
    syscall # Do the syscall

    # Get the file length with lseek(rax, 0, SEEK_END)
    pushq %rax # Save our file descriptor
    pushq %rax # For the next lseek
    pushq %rax # For mmap
    movq $8, %rax # The syscall number for lseek
    popq %rdi # Our file descriptor
    xor %rsi, %rsi # The offset from where we're seeking in the file
    movq $2, %rdx # SEEK_END is 2
    syscall # Do the syscall
    popq %rbx # Put the file descriptor into rbx so it can be last
    pushq %rax # Then save the length
    pushq %rbx # Put the file descriptor on the stack

    # Now go back to the beginning of the file with
    #  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)
    movq $8, %rax # lseek again
    popq %rdi # Put the file descriptor in rdi
    xor %rsi, %rsi # The start of the file
    xor %rdx, %rdx # SEEK_SET is 0
    syscall # Do the syscall

    # Now that we _finally_ have the length of the file,
    #  mmap(0, length, PROT_READ (1), MAP_SHARED (1), fd, 0)
    popq %rdi # The length of the file
    popq %rax # Empty the stack
    movq $1, %rsi # The permissions we want for the pages containing the file contents
    movq $1, %rdx # We want other programs to see our changes (not that there will be any)
    pushq $0 # The offset
    pushq %rdi # Need this for write
    pushq %rdi
    xor %rdi, %rdi # We don't give a sh*t about the address
    pushq %rax # The file descriptor
    movq $9, %rax # mmap's number
    syscall # Damn, that took too much setup

    # Write out the mmap'ed "buffer" with write(stdout, mmap'ed stuff, the length value we've been yeeting around)
    movq %rax, %rdi # mmap'ed stuff
    movq $1, %rax # write's syscall number
    popq %rsi # The length
    syscall # write

    # Exit (note: we could unmap the file, but exiting yeets that sh*t out the window for us)
    mov $60, %rax # exit is 60
    xor %rdi, %rdi # 0
    syscall # Exit
```

Basically, I'm trying to open the filename given as the first argument, then determine how long the file is, mmap it, then write the mmap'd pages to stdout. After some debugging, it seems like I'm passing either invalid flags, length, or an invalid file descriptor.

Again, any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

--- EDIT: here's the output of strace ---

```
execve("./mmap_asm_test", ["./mmap_asm_test", "file"], 0x7ffc2cc61038 /* 48 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558c01b67000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffd5f8eae0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffa4432c000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffa4432ca80) = 0
mprotect(0x558c015ba000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("file", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 5
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE, 0, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(-22, 0x3, 1)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Also, note that this is my first time asking a question on SO, so if there's advice about making my question better, it's welcome.

Comment: EINVAL with mmap is often caused by not having the address (and file offset) page aligned.  What does `strace` show you for the parameters you're passing?  If it was a bad fd, it would be `EBADF`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is caused by somehow losing track of where the file descriptor and length are and passing random/wrong values.

Comment: It's easier if you store the file descriptor and the length in other registers (only `rax`, `rcx` and `r11` are clobbered by a syscall, so even `rdi` could be used to keep the file descriptor. But there are plenty of other registers anyway). If you want to use the stack, it's easier to push/pop and repush on demand rather than push in advance. Anyway, kudos for your commenting style, very well done and actually useful .

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm gonna try making a revised version of the program and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments on this question, I've made a revised version of the program that works as expected:

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:
    # Grab our first argument from the stack
    popq %rdi # This will be argc, which we don't care about
    popq %rdi # Now the executable's path
    popq %rdi # And the first argument, at last

    # Open the file with open(argv[1], 0, O_RDONLY)
    movq $2, %rax # The syscall number for open
    xor %rsi, %rsi # There are no flags we need to specify
    xor %rdx, %rdx # O_RDONLY is 0
    syscall # Do the syscall
    movq %rax, %rdi # Put the file descriptor in rdi for later use

    # Get the file length with lseek(rax, 0, SEEK_END)
    movq $8, %rax # The syscall number for lseek
    xor %rsi, %rsi # The offset from where we're seeking in the file
    movq $2, %rdx # SEEK_END is 2
    syscall # Do the syscall
    movq %rax, %r10 # Save our file length

    # Now go back to the beginning of the file with
    #  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET). The file descriptor should still be in rdi here
    movq $8, %rax # lseek again
    xor %rsi, %rsi # The start of the file
    xor %rdx, %rdx # SEEK_SET is 0
    syscall # Do the syscall

    # Now that we _finally_ have the length of the file,
    #  mmap(0, length, PROT_READ (1), MAP_SHARED (1), fd, 0)
    movq $9, %rax # mmap's number
    xor %r9, %r9 # The offset
    movq %rdi, %r8 # The file descriptor
    movq %r10, %rsi # The file length
    movq $1, %rdx # The permissions we want for the pages containing the file contents
    movq $1, %r10 # We want other programs to see our changes (not that there will be any)
    xor %rdi, %rdi # We don't give a sh*t about the address
    syscall # Damn, that took too much setup

    # Write out the mmap'ed "buffer" with write(stdout, mmap'ed stuff, length)
    movq %rsi, %rdx # The length
    movq %rax, %rsi # mmap'ed stuff
    movq $1, %rax # write's syscall number
    movq $1, %rdi # stdout
    syscall # write

    # Exit (note: we could unmap the file, but exiting yeets that sh*t right out the window for us)
    mov $60, %rax # exit is 60
    xor %rdi, %rdi # 0
    syscall # Exit
```

Thanks for helping me to find a solution.